# Clothes simulation- rigging a ribbon band to a figure's hand

Tags: rigging

[image]I am getting a bit confused here with my work and need help.
I've successfully rigged a full outfit clothes to my figure bone.  But in addition to that, I want to attach a long ribbon band (see pic) to the figure's hand.  So that when the figure is animated, the ribbon band's clothes simulation will follow the hand, but flow like a realistic band of clothes.

I am confused about how to parent the band of clothes to the hand.  Any quick suggestions???

Thanks!
[image: Ribbon band parenting to figure's hand]

Answer (score 2):

To have the cloth move with the hand, you parent it to it. If the cloth will always follow the hand, then you can just select the cloth, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> select the armature and in pose mode select the hand bone, then <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and choose *Bone*. If you want to enable/disable the following then use a [ChildOf constraint](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/87470/935) and animate the influence.

Once the cloth object is following the hand, you use [pinning](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/cloth/settings/cloth_settings.html#pinning) to prevent the cloth simulation causing it to fall away. In edit mode select some vertices at the top of the cloth and [assign them to a vertex group](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/71294/935) and set that group in the cloth pinning option.

[image: cloth pinning]

Comment: Yes, I've tried the ribbon clothes to be parented to the bone, but even with the pinning the clothes doesn't move like a clothes, but moves like a baseball bat.  I've added another image showing this.  Why wouldn't the clothes modifier not work here?

Comment: Sorry- i've discovered the problem.  I didn't catch that the start animation frame was set to 1!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies here- the problem was really simple.  I forgot to correct the start frame of the clothes animation! :(